# Merge Array Issue

Tags: php, arrays

I have several arrays that all have this structure:

```
array (
  526744 => 
  array (
    'completed' => 13,
    'total' => 24,
    'topics' => 
    array (
    ),
    'lessons' => 
    array (
      526745 => 1,
      526747 => 1,
      526749 => 1,
      526751 => 0,
      526757 => 0,
      526759 => 0,
      526761 => 1,
      526763 => 0,
      526765 => 0,
      526767 => 1,
    ),
    'last_id' => 526793,
  ),
  526818 => 
  array (
    'completed' => 0,
    'total' => 22,
    'topics' => 
    array (
    ),
    'lessons' => 
    array (
      526819 => 0,
      526821 => 1,
      526823 => 1,
      526845 => 0,
      526847 => 1,
      526849 => 1,
      526859 => 1,
      526861 => 1,
    ),
    'last_id' => 526861,
  ),
)
```

The number in the outer-most element of the array is a course id. The list of numbers in the inner-most array elements are lesson ids.

I want to merge all of the arrays that contain this structure together. But only ones with the course id of 526744.

If I do something like this:

```
foreach($results2 as $result2) {
    $new_array = unserialize($result2->course_progress);
    $final_array = array_merge($final_array, $new_array);
    $backup_array = $new_array;
}
```

This works fine, but it merges the entire arrays, including all courses.

However if I specify the course_id like this:

```
foreach($results2 as $result2) {
    $new_array = unserialize($result2->course_progress);
    $newarray = $new_array[526744];
    $final_array = array_merge($final_array, $new_array);
    $backup_array = $new_array;
}
```

It no longer merges at all and just lists out the last array for that 1 single course specified.

Any ideas on what is causing this and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Try changing `$newarray = $new_array[526744];` to `$newarray = array($new_array[526744]);`

Comment: That is perfect, thanks. Not sure how to mark your answer as correct as it's entered as a comment.

Comment: Meh I didnt bother creating an answer for such an easy fix, easy mistake we all make. I guess the other guy wanted some extra points.

Comment: I didn't even realise it wasn't you. Sorry. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check your code and found the issue, you have used `$new_array[526744]` which is wrong. it should be `array($new_array[526744])`

Check this code:

```
foreach($results2 as $result2) {
    $new_array = unserialize($result2->course_progress);
    $newarray = array($new_array[526744]);
    $final_array = array_merge($final_array, $new_array);
    $backup_array = $new_array;
}
```